# Product page images slider in one line with supply theme "shopify"

Tags: html, ruby, slider, shopify, liquid

I want to make my images on the product page in one line and adding a slider. I am using a supply theme in shopify. I contact shopify and they told me that I have to pay for an expert, but I want to do it myself. does anyone have any information how to make these changes? Here is an example of product images that I want to add- [product page](https://smileathome.store/products/new-hot-super-powerful-fixate-gel-pad-strong-stick-glue-anywhere-wall-sticker-brand-convenient-gel-pad-portable)

The images are not on the same line.

Comment: You might have to check the theme files and check which .template file has your product images listed. I think it will be a loop with same class or under some other class. So target it using any slider like slick or owl slider plugins.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use a javascript library that will help you build a slider. A very popular library is [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/).

I will recommend you to check out the demo of their [basic carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html).

You can use the basic carousel and have another image tag that you are going to change base onClick on the picture that they click on the carousel.

Answer (score 1):

There is product.liquid file in templat folder you have to edit that find "product.images" and apply Slick Slider on there.
If there any Need i can help you.
I am a shopify Expert with have 3 years experience on theme development and customizations

Comment: TY, will check it and back to you ;)